# How to label a bent arrow on Tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm having an issue with styling a particular type of commutative diagram on Tikzcd. I want to be able to label the arrow coming from C to A in the example diagram below:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{F} \arrow{d} & B \\
C \arrow[u, bend left=16] \arrow[ru, "\psi" description] \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

It seems I cannot put the label after the block where I determine the bend of the arrow, neither can I pass it as a secondary option inside of the block `[]` . So how do I proceed here?

Answer (score 2):

Use more consistently the “modern” interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,"F"] \arrow[d] & B \\
C \arrow[u, shift left=1, bend left=16, "\varphi"]
  \arrow[ru, "\psi" description]
  \arrow[r,"f"'] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some known conflict with packages or some other syntax I need to use it inside an equation environment? For me, your code fails because it thinks the labels are colors.

Comment: @園田海未 To answer your question, a complete minimal example is needed, with your document class and your packages.